# Performance in compare collections method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

I have a method Comparer, with I compare some properties of the objects of two collections.

```
public IEnumerable<Product> Comparer(IEnumerable<Product> collection, IEnumerable<Product> target,  string comparissonKey)
{
    var count = 0;
    var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();                

    var result = new ConcurrentBag<Product>();

    var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2 };

    Parallel.ForEach(collection, parallelOptions, obj =>
    {
        count++;
        if (count == 60000)
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
            //breakpoint
            var aux = stopwatch.Elapsed;
        }
        var comparableObj = obj;
        comparableObj.IsDifferent = false;
        bool hasTargetObject = false;
        comparableObj.Exist = true;

        Product objTarget = null;
        foreach (Product p in target)
        {
            if (obj.Key == p.Key)
            {
                objTarget = p;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (objTarget != null)
        {
           //Do stuff
        }

        if (hasTargetObject) return;

        if (comparableObj.IsDifferent)
        {
            //Do Stuff
        }
    });

    return result.ToList();
}
```

If I execute this method like this, im getting almost 50 seconds to the breakpoint in aux variable breaks. 
If I comment the second foreach (inside the Parallel.Foreach) it breaks in less than 1 second.

I need to find the corresponding object in the target collection using the Key, so I made the second foreach. I used LINQ where clause but I got no better results. Any suggestions to improve this method performance?

Comment: If you want to look things up efficiently by key, why aren't you using something like ConcurrentDictionary?

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet , thanks for your response. Ill check it! But, as i commented in the OP, theres no way to make it faster (not changing the collection type)?

Comment: Well you've fundamentally got an O(M * N) check at the moment. It's simply an unsuitable approach to efficiently joining collections. We also don't know anything about `collection` and `target` - if `target` is actually a database-backed sequence, for example, you may be able to improve matters just by materializing the collection once instead of for every item in `collection`.

Comment: @ggui If you don't want to change the collection type, then what about sorting the target collection? Then, instead of the inner foreach loop, you can just perform a binary search.

if M = collection.count(), N = target.count(), N <= M.
Then the result would be O(Nlog(N)). and it is more efficient  than O(M*M)

Comment: @m1o2 I dont have any restrictions to change the collection type actually. I just want to improve my performance in this inside foreach loop.

Comment: @ggui Do you want to improve Comparer performance or just want to improve your inner foreach performance?

Comment: @Bogdan just the inner foreach is causing trouble.

Comment: @ggui See my answer, the inner foreach should not exist at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve performance by using a dictionary:

```
    public IEnumerable<Product> Comparer(IEnumerable<Product> collection, IEnumerable<Product> target, string comparissonKey)
    {
        var count = 0;
        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        var result = new ConcurrentBag<Product>();
        var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2 };

        // create a dictionary for fast lookup
        var targetDictionary = target.ToDictionary(p => p.Key);

        Parallel.ForEach(collection, parallelOptions, obj =>
        {
            count++;
            if (count == 60000)
            {
                stopwatch.Stop();
                //breakpoint
                var aux = stopwatch.Elapsed;
            }
            var comparableObj = obj;
            comparableObj.IsDifferent = false;
            bool hasTargetObject = false;
            comparableObj.Exist = true;

            Product objTarget = null;

            // lookup using dictionary
            if (targetDictionary.TryGetValue(obj.Key, out objTarget))
            {
                //Do stuff
            }

            if (hasTargetObject) return;

            if (comparableObj.IsDifferent)
            {
                //Do Stuff
            }
        });

        return result.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If Key is indeed a key
Then use HashSet as it has IntersetWith and is smoking fast
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx

On your class Product you will need to overwrite GetHashCode and Equals
Use the Key for the GetHashCode

[Override GetHashCode on overriding Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182358.aspx)